# PHP, MySql: Seat Number Not Assigning Properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a code for automatically assigning seat for my airline booking website.
At first, when I book for 4 people for a particular date it works well i.e. it assigns 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D for the passengers.
But the next time, when I book for 4 people for a different date than before, it doesn't assign properly i.e. it assigns 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B instead of 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D.

Here is the piece of code that I am using.

```
<?php
$seat="";  
$s="";
function f1() 
{
  require 'connection.php'; 
$from=$_SESSION['fro']; 
  $to=$_SESSION['to']; 
  $date1=$_SESSION['dep']; 
  $air=$_SESSION['airl']; 
  $count=1; 
$n=array("A", "B", "C", "D");

while($count<=5)    
      {

  for($x=0; $x < count($n); $x++)
    {
  global $seat;
      $check="
SELECT * 
  FROM passenger_records 
 WHERE pas_depdate='$date1' 
   AND pas_air='$air' 
   AND pas_frmcity='$from' 
   AND pas_tocity='$to' 
   AND (pas1_seat='$seat' OR pas2_seat='$seat') 
    OR (pas3_seat='$seat' OR pas4_seat='$seat')";
      $result=$conn->query($check);
        if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
     $seat=$count.$n[$x];
    }
      }           
$check="
SELECT * 
  FROM passenger_records 
 WHERE pas_depdate='$date1' 
   AND pas_air='$air' 
   AND pas_frmcity='$from' 
   AND pas_tocity='$to' 
   AND (pas1_seat='$seat' OR pas2_seat='$seat') 
   OR (pas3_seat='$seat' OR pas4_seat='$seat')";
            $result=$conn->query($check);
           if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
             $count++;
            }
           else
             break;
    }
    if($count==6)
    {
      $seat="";
    }
return $seat;
}
    if($cls=="First Class")
    {
       if(!$pas1=="")
          {

       $seat1=f1();
       echo $seat1."<BR>";
   $sq = "UPDATE `passenger_records` SET `pas1_seat` = '{$seat1}' WHERE `passenger_records`.`pas_id` = '$id'";
   $result=$conn->query($sq);

      }
   if(!$pas2=="")
      {

       $seat2=f1();
   $sq = "UPDATE passenger_records SET pas2_seat = '{$seat2}' WHERE passenger_records.pas_id = '$id'";
   $result=$conn->query($sq);
   echo $seat2."<BR>";
      }
   if(!$pas3=="")
      {

       $seat3=f1();
   $sq = "UPDATE passenger_records SET pas3_seat = '{$seat3}' WHERE passenger_records.pas_id = '$id'";
   $result=$conn->query($sq);
   echo $seat3."<BR>";
      }
   if(!$pas4=="")
      {
       $seat4=f1();
   $sq = "UPDATE `passenger_records` SET `pas4_seat` = '{$seat4}' WHERE `passenger_records`.`pas_id` = '$id'";
   $result=$conn->query($sq);
   echo $seat4."<BR>";
      }
}
?>
```

Please help and fix the error as I need to submit the project to school very 
soon.

Comment: Please indent your code properly so it's easier to read and to follow the flow. Also, when you post a bunch of code that you're having issues with, you should include the table structure, example data, comments about what the different parts suppose to do and what debugging you've done and the result of it. Basically narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select statement for checking the seats is incorrect.

The conditions for testing the 3rd and 4th seat positions are
separated from the rest of the conditions by an upper level 'OR' conditional

```
SELECT * 
FROM passenger_records 
WHERE pas_depdate='$date1' 
AND pas_air='$air' 
AND pas_frmcity='$from' 
AND pas_tocity='$to' 
AND (pas1_seat='$seat' OR pas2_seat='$seat') 
OR (pas3_seat='$seat' OR pas4_seat='$seat')
```

Replace with query with the following format

```
SELECT * 
FROM passenger_records 
WHERE pas_depdate='$date1' 
AND pas_air='$air' 
AND pas_frmcity='$from' 
AND pas_tocity='$to' 
AND (pas1_seat='$seat' OR pas2_seat='$seat' OR pas3_seat='$seat' OR pas4_seat='$seat')
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting the code. I am very obliged for your help.